# Magento 2 checkout_onepage_controller_success_action event not fired

Tags: php, events, observers, magento-2.0

I am working on Magento 2 platform.
I have created my custom modue name MerchantTrack.
Into events.xml (MagentoSite\app\code\Magento\MerchantTrack\Checkout\etc\frontend\events.xml) written code
below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action ">
        <observer name="merchanttrack_checkout_onepage_controller_success_action" instance="Magento\MerchantTrack\Checkout\Observer\MyObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Into MyObserver.php(MagentoSite\app\code\Magento\MerchantTrack\Checkout\Observer\MyObserver.php) written code below

```
<?php
 
 namespace Magento\MerchantTrack\Checkout\Observer; 

 use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    class MyObserver implements ObserverInterface { 


        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
            echo $orderId = $orderIds[0]; exit;
        }
   }
```

When placed order, into success (/MagentoSite/checkout/onepage/success/) page i can not see orderid which i echo into observer page. So I can not understand my event is fired or not.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add logger in observer file, so you can track your event is working or not

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow module directory structure properly.
See:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/module-file-structure.html#module-file-structure

MagentoSite\app\code\Magento\MerchantTrack\Checkout\etc\frontend\events.xml

You have created extra folder i.e **Magento**

Your directory should look like this.
MagentoSite\app\code\MerchantTrack\Checkout\etc\frontend\events.xml